# Как передавать и принимать данные на сайте через flask?

Tags: python, ajax, flask

У меня есть flask. html должен отправлять данные по кнопке в flask. А python на другой стороне должен их принять и вписать в сайт. Без перезагрузки страницы. Если коротко. Как принимать и менять значения блоков html с помощью flask, БЕЗ ПЕРЕЗАГРУЗКИ СТРАНИЦЫ. Про ajax я знаю, но он лишь принимает данные но не как не отправляет обратно в html.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если коротко мне нужно что-то такое. https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.08b352f2-632b1c79-4c683891-74722d776562/https/www.geeksforgeeks.org/flask-form-submission-without-page-reload/
Но что бы ajax не только передавал значения. Но и потом принимал их от python кода. А потом я это использую в html

Comment: Я искал подробное объяснение без воды, так как люди любят тупо вставлять свой огромный код. А ты разбирайся. Потратил на это 3 дня и нашёл это видео.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nF9riePnm80&list=LL&index=1&t=110s&ab_channel=RedEyedCoderClub
Для новичка будет сложно понятно что к чему, так как оно не на русском. Но только в этом видео без воды объясняется как что делать.

Comment: 1) `html` не умеет ничего отправлять во flask. HTML - это разметка. 2) `Flask` не умеет ничего вставлять в уже отправленный html без перезагрузки страницы. 3) AJAX - сам по себе ничего не принимает и не отправляет. Этим занимается JavaScript. Ajax -это подход к организации отзывчивых интерфейсов с помощью асинхронных запросов. И да, Вам нужен именно такой подход. 4) Вы отправляете асинхронный запрос с помощью JavaScript. 5) Вы принимаете ответ на асинхронный запрос с помощью JavaScript. 6) Вы вставляете полученные данные с помощью JavaScript... Удачи!